# Remove highly correlated variables

Tags: r, function, subset, correlation

I have a huge dataframe 5600 X 6592 and I want to remove any variables that are correlated to each other more than 0.99 I do know how to do this the long way, step by step i.e. forming a correlation matrix, rounding the values, removing similar ones and use the indexing to get my "reduced" data again.

```
cor(mydata)
mydata <- round(mydata,2)
mydata <- mydata[,!duplicated (mydata)]
## then do the indexing...
```

I would like to know if this could be done in short command, or some advanced function. I'm learning how to make use of the powerful tools in the R language, which avoids such long unnecessary commands

I was thinking of something like

```
mydata <- mydata[, which(apply(mydata, 2, function(x) !duplicated(round(cor(x),2))))]
```

Sorry I know the above command doesn't work, but I hope I would be able to do this.

a play-data that applies to the question:

```
mydata <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 366L, 65L, 43L, 456L, 876L, 
78L, 687L, 378L, 378L, 34L, 53L, 43L), V2 = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
366L, 65L, 43L, 456L, 876L, 78L, 687L, 378L, 378L, 34L, 53L, 
41L), V3 = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2010L, 
20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), V4 = c(2L, 10L, 31L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 52L, 1L, 2L, 52L, 6L, 2L, 1L), V5 = c(4L, 10L, 31L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 52L, 1L, 2L, 52L, 6L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this and certainly some better than this, but this should work. I basically just set the upper triangle to be zero and then remove any rows that have values over 0.99.

```
tmp <- cor(data)
tmp[upper.tri(tmp)] <- 0
diag(tmp) <- 0

# Above two commands can be replaced with 
# tmp[!lower.tri(tmp)] <- 0

 
data.new <- 
  data[, !apply(tmp, 2, function(x) any(abs(x) > 0.99, na.rm = TRUE))]
head(data.new)

   V2 V3 V5
1   2 10  4
2   2 20 10
3   5 10 31
4   4 20  2
5 366 10  2
6  65 20  5
```

Comment: Thanks David, it does the Job, although I don't know what the upper triangle is! I found the R help page but I cannot really understand what it does! :)

Comment: @Error404 `upper.tri` just fills that part of a matrix with "TRUE" (and the rest is zero aka FALSE) , so `tmp[upper.tri(tmp)]` selects only the upper triangle portion of `tmp` .

Comment: Might be clearer if you do `data[, apply(tmp,2,function(x) all(x<=0.99))]`  Don't use no double negatives :-)

Comment: Interesting simplification of the command :) I'll play around with the upper triangle. Thanks buddy

Comment: Hi can anyone help when i use norm.num[, apply(tmp,2,function(x) any(x > 0.99))] on my data set, i get error message saying  Error in `[.data.frame`(norm.num, , !apply(tmp, 2, function(x) any(abs(x) >  :  undefined columns selected

Comment: I edited the answer so that high degree of negative correlation would be also accounted + also deal with missing values.

Answer (score 55):

This is my R code this would be helpfull for you

```
library('caret')

df1 = read.csv("stack.csv")

print (df1)

     GA     PN     PC   MBP    GR    AP
1 0.033  6.652  6.681 0.194 0.874 3.177
2 0.034  9.039  6.224 0.194 1.137 3.400
3 0.035 10.936 10.304 1.015 0.911 4.900
4 0.022 10.110  9.603 1.374 0.848 4.566
5 0.035  2.963 17.156 0.599 0.823 9.406
6 0.033 10.872 10.244 1.015 0.574 4.871
7 0.035 21.694 22.389 1.015 0.859 9.259
8 0.035 10.936 10.304 1.015 0.911 4.500


df2 = cor(df1)
hc = findCorrelation(df2, cutoff=0.3) # putt any value as a "cutoff" 
hc = sort(hc)
reduced_Data = df1[,-c(hc)]
print (reduced_Data)

     GA     PN    GR    AP
1 0.033  6.652 0.874 3.177
2 0.034  9.039 1.137 3.400
3 0.035 10.936 0.911 4.900
4 0.022 10.110 0.848 4.566
5 0.035  2.963 0.823 9.406
6 0.033 10.872 0.574 4.871
7 0.035 21.694 0.859 9.259
8 0.035 10.936 0.911 4.500
```

and to write down a reduced data into new csv just use:

```
write.csv(reduced_Data, file = "outfile.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: where have you defined findCorrelation?

Comment: @AnkitDhingra - `findCorrelation` is a function built into the `caret` package that jax loaded on his first line.

Comment: @JAX, you're a genious! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

@David 
A small change in your code make it **more robust** to *negative correlation* , by providing

```
abs(x) > 0.99
```

instead of only

```
x > 0.99
```

> `data.new <- data[,!apply(tmp,2,function(x) any(abs(x) > 0.99))]`

cheers..!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `recipes` package has the `step_corr()` function to facilitate this sort of data preprocessing:

```r
library(recipes)

mydata <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 366L, 65L, 43L, 456L, 876L, 
                                78L, 687L, 378L, 378L, 34L, 53L, 43L), V2 = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
                                                                              366L, 65L, 43L, 456L, 876L, 78L, 687L, 378L, 378L, 34L, 53L, 
                                                                              41L), V3 = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2010L, 
                                                                                           20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), V4 = c(2L, 10L, 31L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                 2L, 5L, 1L, 52L, 1L, 2L, 52L, 6L, 2L, 1L), V5 = c(4L, 10L, 31L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 52L, 1L, 2L, 52L, 6L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -16L))

# initialize pre-processing recipe 
recipe(x = mydata) |> 
  # perform variable selection using 0.99 threshold
  step_corr(recipes::all_numeric(), threshold = 0.99) |> 
  # prepare recipe
  prep() |> 
  # extract data from trained recipe
  juice()
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>       V2    V3    V4
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     2    10     2
#>  2     2    20    10
#>  3     5    10    31
#>  4     4    20     2
#>  5   366    10     2
#>  6    65    20     5
#>  7    43     1     2
#>  8   456     0     5
#>  9   876     1     1
#> 10    78  2010    52
#> 11   687    20     1
#> 12   378    10     2
#> 13   378    10    52
#> 14    34    10     6
#> 15    53    10     2
#> 16    41    10     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>